# JQuery ready doesn't appear to fire

Tags: jquery

Ok, I'm stumped. I have pages where jquery works but for some reason this doesn't.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
jQuery(function($) { alert() })(jQuery);
</script>
</html>
```

I suspect it is the link I'm using for jquery but the ready function isn't firing and I can't see a reason why.

Comment: Try putting this: `alert('this alerts.');`

Comment: Why did this get voted down? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: It wasn't me @nickcoxdotme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this it works!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This works.  I thought I had done exactly the same thing but I couldn't get it to work so I tried the syntax in the question. Thanks for posting the response. --Alan

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('foo')
});
//OR
$(function() { 
   alert('foo'); 
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

its :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
                       {
                          alert('alert');
                       });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$( function() { alert("blah!!"); });
```

or

```
jQuery( function() { alert("blah!"); });
```

or

```
$(document).ready( function() { });
```

or

```
$(window).load( function() { });
```

or

```
jQuery(window).load( function() { });
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() { });
```

Thousands of options are there for you!